# fill color for each table cell with color-option listed in drop menu only if clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to create table by clicking button where as table contains columns and rows specified by user. After that,we have to fill each table cell by performing onclick with the color listed in the drop down list menu.

The below code snippet is to create table with user's input. I don't know to proceed further. How to perform this ?

[image: **click here to view the Expected Output **]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style>
.highlighted {
    background: red;
}
    table{
     width:500px;
  height:500px;
 }
 table td{
  padding:10px;
  margin:10px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
 }
    table tr{
height:100px;
}
</style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>


    function createTable(){
     
 mytable = $('<table></table>').attr({ id: "basicTable" });
 var rows = new Number($("#rows").val());
 var cols = new Number($("#columns").val());
 var tr = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  var row = $('<tr></tr>').attr({ class: ["class1", "class2", "class3"].join(' ') }).appendTo(mytable);
  for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
   $('<td></td>').text("").appendTo(row); 
  }
      
 }
 console.log("TTTTT:"+mytable.html());
 mytable.appendTo("#matrixTableId");        
  
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
Enter Rows <input type='text' id='rows'><br>
Enter Cols <input type='text' id='columns'><br>
<input type="button" onclick="createTable();" name="save" value="Form Matrix" /><br>
Choose Color: <select id="dropDown">
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <div id="matrixTableId">
    
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Start by changing `class: ["class1", "class2", "class3"]` to a class that exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this : You can add a click event handler for all `td` and set background-color as a value from dropDown.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style>
.highlighted {
    background: red;
}
    table{
     width:500px;
  height:500px;
 }
 table td{
  padding:10px;
  margin:10px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
 }
    table tr{
height:100px;
}
</style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>


    function createTable(){
     
 mytable = $('<table></table>').attr({ id: "basicTable" });
 var rows = new Number($("#rows").val());
 var cols = new Number($("#columns").val());
 var tr = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  var row = $('<tr></tr>').attr({ class: ["class1", "class2", "class3"].join(' ') }).appendTo(mytable);
  for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
   $('<td></td>').text("").appendTo(row); 
  }
      
 }
 console.log("TTTTT:"+mytable.html());
 mytable.appendTo("#matrixTableId");        
  
}
 
$(function(){
  $(document).on("click","table tr td", function(){
    var color = $('#dropDown').val();
    $(this).css('background-color', color);
  });
   });
</script>
</head>
<body>
Enter Rows <input type='text' id='rows'><br>
Enter Cols <input type='text' id='columns'><br>
<input type="button" onclick="createTable();" name="save" value="Form Matrix" /><br>
Choose Color: <select id="dropDown">
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <div id="matrixTableId">
    
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You should handle `onclick` event of `td` and set background of clicked `td` to `select` value

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style>
.highlighted {
    background: red;
}
    table{
     width:500px;
  height:500px;
 }
 table td{
  padding:10px;
  margin:10px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
 }
    table tr{
height:100px;
}
</style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>


    function createTable(){
     
 mytable = $('<table></table>').attr({ id: "basicTable" });
 var rows = new Number($("#rows").val());
 var cols = new Number($("#columns").val());
 var tr = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  var row = $('<tr></tr>').attr({ class: ["class1", "class2", "class3"].join(' ') }).appendTo(mytable);
  for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
   var $td = $('<td></td>');
   $td.text("").appendTo(row); 
   $td.click(function(){
     $(this).css('background',$('#dropDown').val());
   });
  }
      
 }
 console.log("TTTTT:"+mytable.html());
 mytable.appendTo("#matrixTableId");        
  
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
Enter Rows <input type='text' id='rows'><br>
Enter Cols <input type='text' id='columns'><br>
<input type="button" onclick="createTable();" name="save" value="Form Matrix" /><br>
Choose Color: <select id="dropDown">
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <div id="matrixTableId">
    
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```